# Create a PHP Function out of a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of PHP functions for a URL shortener. **I'd like to add another function which concerns updating a whole column in a MySQL table**. So far I found the query which is: UPDATE urls SET redirect = 'http://example.com'
I'd like to have a text input where once I type a new URL and click "UPDATE ALL", the whole column in the database changes without having to do it from the database using the query I mentioned above. The only thing that stops me from doing so is the function(BOTTOM).
Here are the functions I mentioned earlier:

```
function createLink($slug,$url,$title,$disc,$thumb,$redirect){
    global $nsqlQuery;
        $f = array('slug','url','title','disc','thumb','redirect','time');
        $v = array($slug,$url,$title,$disc,$thumb,$redirect,time());

        $row = array_combine($f,$v);
    $result = $nsqlQuery->insert("urls",$row);
return $result ? $result : false;
}

function getLink($by='NA',$val='NA'){
    global $nsqlQuery;
        if($by=='NA'):
            $where = null;
        else:
            $f = array($by);
            $v = array($val);
            $where = array_combine($f,$v);
        endif;
    $result = $nsqlQuery->select("urls",'*',$where);
return $result ? $result : false;
}

function deleteLink($id){
    global $nsqlQuery;
        $f = array('id');
        $v = array($id);

        $where = array_combine($f,$v);
    $result = $nsqlQuery->delete("urls",$where);
return $result ? $result : false;
}
```

Here's the public function that concerns updating the table and setting a new value to a certain column.

```
public function update($table,$row,$where,$where_condition=null,$dev='OFF'){
    $query = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".$this->getSetClause($row)." ".$this->getWhereClause($where,$where_condition);
    if($dev=='ON')
        return $query;
    $response = $this->query($query);

    return $response ? true : false;
}
```

Here's my progress so far which prompts a 500 error.

```
function updateRedirect($redirect){
global $nsqlQuery;

    $where = $redirect;
$result = $nsqlQuery->update("urls",$where) SET ".$nsqlQuery->select("urls",'*',$where);
 return $result ? $result : false;
 }
```

[The whole nsqlQuery.php file just in case.](http://www.filedropper.com/nsqlquery)

Comment: if i read your question right, cause i am making plenty of mistakes. your concern is error 500 hundred, error 500 normally cuased due to file permission, if you have htaccess check that, or it might be your error reporting off, turn it on, it may display you different error.

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 I've already solved this issue. I only get a 500 error when a php code isn't written properly.

Comment: that the same thing i told you, your error reporting is, as it should produce an errror, and it off that's it produce 500 error, on critical error. any way its good you were able to solved it.